# WiFi state is not enabling

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am trying to create a widget for enabling and disabling the wifi.

```
if(myWifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
            System.out.println("Toggle Wifi Enabled going to disable");
            myWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Wifi Disabled going to enable ");

            myWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
            System.out.println("WI: "+myWifiManager.isWifiEnabled());
        }
```

This is the code i am using the disabling part is working fine but the enabling part is not working fine. Soon after enabling the wifi i am printing the wifi state i am getting it as false.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how to turn on and turn off wifi in android.

First you need to declare the following in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
```

After doing it that on your Activity class

```
private WifiManager wifiManager;
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
 ....................
 wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
 if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
 wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
 }else{
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
}
```

}

***Explanation***

**Get the Wifi service from our system**

```
wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

**Check the our wifi is currently turned on or turned off**

```
if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
```

**Turn on/off our wifi**
    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled();

**Reference**

[WifiEnabler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html)

http://google-androidlovers.blogspot.com/2012/01/scan-for-wireless-networks-in-android.html

http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-platform-apps/Settings/com/android/settings/wifi/WifiApEnabler.java.htm

Comment: UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS is for system application only

Comment: Aside from `UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS` (which @Superbiji is right, should not be used) the other permissions are `normal` level. So Android won't yell at you if you try to do something which requires those permissions. IIRC you won't even see anything in logcat.

Answer (score 1):

> Deprecated: Starting with Build.VERSION_CODES#Q, applications are not
> allowed to enable/disable Wi-Fi. Compatibility Note: For applications
> targeting android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES#Q or above, this API will
> always fail and return false. If apps are targeting an older SDK
> (android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES#P or below), they can continue to use
> this API.

([Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#setwifienabled))

So this will only work for devices with android Pie and below.

Answer (score 0):

Download this example it is what you want

https://github.com/siddhpuraamitr/WIfi-Toggle-Widget