# Android : How to ask permission to wireless?

Tags: java, android

Little concern for my app which works great with Android 4.4 but Android 6.0 bug because I need permission to allow disabling wifi:

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifi.setWifiEnabled(false); // true or false to activate/deactivate wifi
```

Do you know how can I apply for permission?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WiFi state is not enabling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709188/wifi-state-is-not-enabling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to declare it in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Android M (6.0+) user prompted runtime permission is NOT required for CHANGE_WIFI_STATE, because it is one of the safe/normal ones.

[Android API Guide - Normal Permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/normal-permissions.html)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have this two in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

If the android SDK is >= 6.0 you need to request those permissions at run time, example:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
// MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
// app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
// result of the request.
```

Check out more over here:

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html